# Readig XML file from Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have some `XML` file which contains "Squishreport". 
I want to look for some special value of all nodes under condition. To do so, I have written a code in `Perl` that the main function is as follows:

```
sub FileCount
{
chdir( $dir ) or die "Couldn't go inside $dir directory, $!";
opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$0: $dir: $!\n";
while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    # We only want files
     next unless (-f "$dir/$file");
    # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .xml
     next unless ($file =~ m/$suff$/);

     my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

    # Iterate the entries

    for my $test ($xml->findnodes('/SquishReport/test/test')) {
        my $name_test = $test->findvalue('@name');
        # trim the value
         s/\A\s*//, s/\s*\z// for my $value_test = $test->textContent;

        print "Test Name = $name_test \n";

        for my $result ($test->findnodes('/verification/result')) {
            my $type_result = $result->findvalue('@type');

            # trim the value
             s/\A\s*//, s/\s*\z// for my $value = $result->textContent;
             print "$type_result = $value \n";
            if (($type_result eq "WARNING") || ($type_result eq "FAIL") || ($type_result eq "ERROR") || ($type_result eq "FATAL")){
                print "$type_result = $value \n";
                print "***********  $name_test is not OK *********** \n\n "; 
            }
            else{
                print "***********  $name_test is OK *********** \n\n ";
            }
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    #}
     print "$file\n";       
     $count = $count + 1;
}
closedir($dh);
if ($count eq 1){
    print "There is only one file in '' $dir '' directory.";
}
else{
    print "There are $count files in '' $dir '' directory.";
}
```

}

The goal is looking for the first test and type the name. Now if it there is `PASS` in `type` then write the name of test and says is OK, otherwise writes is not OK.

I am not sure if the code is the right code for the structure/goal.

My problem is that the inner `for` loop does not work. the instruction for `XML` file is as:

```
<SquishReport>
     <test name="abcd">
         <test name="EFGH">
             <verification .......>
                  <result type="PASS">
                         <description>version check test case passes!</description>
                         <description type="DETAILED"></description>
    .
    .
    .         
         <test name=IJKLM">
             <verification .......>
                  <result type="PASS">
                         <description>version check test case passes!</description>
                         <description type="DETAILED"></description>
```

**Edit: **
Here is the `XML` file:

```
<SquishReport>
<test name="mat_tst_versions">
    <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:49:54+02:00"/>
    <message type="FATAL" time="2015-06-16T13:50:54+02:00">
        <description><![CDATA[Execution error]]></description>
        <description type="DETAILED"><![CDATA[squishrunner exited with code 3 when executing tst_start_app]]></description>
    </message>
    <test name="tst_check_versions">
        <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:50:55+02:00"/>
        <message line="274" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\utilities.py" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[is 64 bit windows version: True]]></description>
        </message>            
        <message line="124" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_check_versions\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[    path exists!]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="129" type="FAIL" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_check_versions\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[expected version: 1.0.0.107]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="132" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_check_versions\test.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00">
                <description>version check test case passes!</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:50:59+02:00"/>
    </test>        
    <test name="tst_scheduler_1">
        <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:51:00+02:00"/>
        <message line="62" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:00+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[count = 0]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="125" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:06+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[duration of start of C: 5132ms]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="172" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[application name = C]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="184" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[start application: C]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="213" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[Scheduler Label exists]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="219" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:51:19+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[Scheduler Counter exists]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="368" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
            <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:01+02:00">
                <description>different types elements</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <verification line="369" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
            <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:01+02:00">
                <description>name_list= ['Scheduler', 'NCU', 'PLCSimAdv', 'simNCK', 'MCP']</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <verification line="370" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
            <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:01+02:00">
                <description>typ_list= ['Scheduler', u'NCU', u'PLCSimAdv']</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="393" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[:840evoVC.lblClockCounter_Edit = 0]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="411" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
            <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
                <description>scheduler counter 1. read, n=0: Scheduler= 0</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <verification line="414" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py">
            <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
                <description>scheduler counter 2. read, n=0: Scheduler= 0</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="421" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:08+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[scheduler counter 1. read < counter 2. read, n=0: Scheduler= 0]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="484" type="ERROR" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_scheduler_1\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:29+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[Script Error]]></description>
            <description type="DETAILED"><![CDATA[LookupError: Object ':840evoVC.chkSchedule_CheckBox_2' not ready.]]></description>
        </message>
        <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:52:29+02:00"/>
    </test>
    <test name="tst_run_plc">
        <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:52:30+02:00"/>
        <verification line="45" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_run_plc\test.py">
            <result type="FAIL" time="2015-06-16T13:52:30+02:00">
                <description>user path folder already exists!</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="125" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:34+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[duration of start of 840evoVC: 4263ms]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="54" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:34+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[start ok, duration = 4263000]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="64" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:34+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[application started: 840evoVC]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="78" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:39+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[PLC Sim Advanced tmp user files are the expected files]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="263" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:45+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[all applications are closed]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="87" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst_840evovc\tst_run_plc\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:45+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[close application ok]]></description>
        </message>
        <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:52:45+02:00"/>
    </test>
    <test name="tst_app_resources">
        <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:52:47+02:00"/>
        <message line="65" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_app_resources\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:49+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[count:0]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="125" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:53+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[duration of start: 4176ms]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="73" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_app_resources\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:52:53+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[start ok, duration = 4176000]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="43" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\win32utilities.py" time="2015-06-16T13:53:00+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[Application 840evovc only exists once]]></description>
        </message>            
        <message line="138" type="ERROR" file="C:\test\mat_tst_\tst_app_resources\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:53:30+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[Script Error]]></description>
            <description type="DETAILED"><![CDATA[LookupError: Object ':chkSchedule_CheckBox_2' not ready.
                Called from:
            C:\test\mat_tst\tst_app_resources\test.py: 82]]></description>
        </message>
        <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:53:30+02:00"/>
    </test>
    <test name="tst_reset">
        <prolog time="2015-06-16T13:53:32+02:00"/>   
        <message line="260" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[Process exited.]]></description>          
        </message>
        <message line="263" type="LOG" file="C:\test\scripts\start_stop.py" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[all applications are closed]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="284" type="LOG" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_reset\test.py" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
            <description><![CDATA[application closed]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="287" type="" name="" file="C:\test\mat_tst\tst_reset\test.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00">
                <description>tst_reset_1 ok</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:56:12+02:00"/>
    </test>
    <epilog time="2015-06-16T13:56:13+02:00"/>
</test>
```

Comment: Please make the XML valid so we can test with it.

Comment: @simbabque Please see the edited version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't help:

- `if ($count eq 1)` - that should be `==`
- Rather than `readdir` with filtering, why not just use `glob ( "$dir/*.xml" )`?
- `my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);` could be breaking, because you're *not* changing directory. (so location should probably be `$dir/$file` - a problem which using the above `glob` avoids)

However the core of your problem is this:

```
for my $result ( $test->findnodes('/verification/result') ) {
```

Change it to:

```
for my $result ( $test->findnodes('./verification/result') ) {
```

And you'll get:

```
Test Name = tst_app_resources 

Test Name = tst_reset 
***********  tst_reset is OK ***********
```